# trying to retrieve specific data from mongodb database but showing undefined in console

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
app.get("/admin/:id",isLoggedAdmin,function(req,res){

    Advocate.findById(req.params.id, function(err,advocateFound){

    if(err){

            console.log(err);
        }
    else{
        Advocatecase.find({uid:advocateFound.uid},function(err,allcase){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                   }
            else
            {
                console.log(allcase.name);
                res.render("show",{advocatecase:allcase,advocate:advocateFound});
            }
        });
      }
    });
});
```

**My schema**

```
var mongoose=require("mongoose");

var advocatecaseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    uid:String,
    cid:String,
    name:String,
    status:String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Advocatecase",advocatecaseSchema);
```

**console**

```
(node:5728) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
(node:5728) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
```

Server started....

```
undefined
```

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(allcase)` placed above `console.log(allcase.name);`?

Comment: [
  {
    _id: 5e9f3126523912382c0bf102,
    uid: '8521',
    cid: '4545',
    name: 'chetan case',
    status: 'won',
    __v: 0
  }
]

Answer (score 0):

`.find` returns an array. Either change it to find_one, or do `allcase[0].name`